# Non Factoring of quadratic

Tags: plotting, algebraic-manipulation

```
IB[k1_, k2_, c_, 
  K_] = (((k1 + k2)/2)^2 - 2 c ((k1 + k2)/2) K - K (4 + 3 c^2 K))/K^2
p = 50; q = 50; c = 1; K = 4;
ContourPlot[IB[k1, k2, c, K] - c == 0, {k1, -p, p}, {k2, -q, q}, 
 PlotLabel -> StrLinePair, ContourStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1.9]
Clear["Global`*"];
Factor[IB[k1, k2, c, K] - c]
```

[image]

Plotting to a pair of straight lines alright, the same expression does not seem to find the factors. Please help find what I missed over here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```Clear["Global`*"];``` will clear everything. Try moving it before the function.

Comment: Moved, even then no change.  Using  Version 11. (Cleared before itself in order to get non-numerical algebraic factors. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the plot, clear variables, but not the function definition.
(Using GothicCapitalK after @Artes comment: Thanks). In general, using upper case var names is not recommended.

```
Clear[k1, k2, c, \[GothicCapitalK]]

FunctionExpand[IB[k1, k2, c, \[GothicCapitalK]] - c]
```

> ```
> -c + (1/4 (k1 + k2)^2 - 
>   c (k1 + k2) \[GothicCapitalK] - \[GothicCapitalK] (4 + 
>      3 c^2 \[GothicCapitalK]))/\[GothicCapitalK]^2
> ```

To get what's shown in your plot:

```
FunctionExpand[
  IB[k1, k2, c, \[GothicCapitalK]] - c] /. {c -> 
   1, \[GothicCapitalK] -> 4}
```

> -1 + 1/16 (-64 - 4 (k1 + k2) + 1/4 (k1 + k2)^2)

You can try `Factor[...]` to see the difference.

Comment: The capital `K` is a symbol of of the Wolfram language, you shouldn't use it as a variable name.